# Any designers or libraries for creating "Vista-style" web pages?

Tags: user-interface, windows-vista

I'm looking for a way to create websites with the *cool stylings* of Windows Vista, like what is shown in this screenshot (taken from one of Microsoft's websites):

[image: Microsoft Update Catalog]

Any suggestions? I'd prefer an integrated designer / IDE, but libraries or templates might also help.

Answer (score 4):

**FYI, the answers before this were in response to a very poorly worded question. The OP did not make it clear that they were after a web page. Thanks to [Shog9](https://stackoverflow.com/users/811/shog9) for picking up the slack there.**

This is NOTHING to do with WPF or VS 2008. Its a WEB application!

Lots of control vendors have produced some great looking controls, check out the [ASP.NET controls gallery](http://www.asp.net/Community/Control-gallery/) there is some cool stuff there. Another well-known vendor is [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) who have created some real nice [ASP.NET AJAX controls](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/overview.aspx).

Note, this is not to promote their tools, I personally have not used them, they are popular, and it's just to give you the heads up.

In short, the look is pretty much fancy imagery. Unless [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/) is used, which uses a subset of WPF and requires the plugin to be installed on the users browser, and requires VS2008 to create.

In terms of the screen shot, most of that is nice imagery, the buttons are probably rendered like that because you are running Vista, however, they could also be replicated without Vista. **The page you show is not a Silverlight page, so it is not a requirement.**

Have a Google for "ASP.NET vista style controls" there's tons of people after the same stuff :)

Comment: To be fair to previous answers... I edited the OP heavily. The original version was so vague that it could easily have been interpreted as a question on writing a web browser UI, since the only source of information was the screenshot.

Comment: Just checked edit history, I see what you mean. Removed my comment RE answers. Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a matter of what software to use - use whatever you normally use to design websites. If you want to make a web page that looks like one you see online, you can very easily obtain:

1. The HTML markup on the page
2. The CSS style sheets used by the page
3. The images used on the page
4. The Javascript used on the page (although this is less likely to be useful, as in most cases it will have been compacted and obfuscated).

Answer (score 0):

The "cool Vista stylings" are done using [WPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation), for which you'll need [Visual Studio 2008](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/default.aspx). 90-day trial downloads are [here](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/vstudio/products/aa700831.aspx). The "Express Products" (free, stripped-down versions) are [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/).

Answer (score 0):

Also Delphi 2009 ;-).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned Visual Studio 2008 has WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation) based development tools in it. Have a look in your Project templates for WPF Application along with WPF Browser Application and WPF User Control Library. All of these pertain to Vista WPF.